# EF Core - Get access to the DbContext using the entity itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using the EF Core 3.1. My entity classes look like this:

```
    public partial class TestTable : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable{

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(System.String.Empty);

        private DateTime? _Updatime;
        public virtual DateTime? UpdDatime
        {
            get
            {
                return this._UpdDatime;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._UpdDatime != value)
                {
                    this.SendPropertyChanging("UpdDatime");
                    this._UpdDatime = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("UpdDatime");
                }
            }
        }
.....
```

Notice that every ModelClass is a partial class. Because I use a generator to to create my model, using partial classes I can extend these.

The builder looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestTable>().Property(x => x.UpdDatime).HasColumnName(@"UPD_DATIME").HasColumnType(@"DATE").ValueGeneratedNever();
```

and I am able to extend the ModelBuilder. Any Ideas how could I make a connection between my entity and the DbContext which instantiated it?

So that I can access the DbContext in the TestTable.partial

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the problem that you want to solve that way?

Comment: I am trying to simulate a trigger-like behaviour. I've already accomplished to call specific Methods if a entity is about to or has been saved in the DB. Especially the pre save triggers have to run within the same transaction to keep consistency, so I cannot simply create a new DbContext and do work

Comment: Trigger-like behavior in EF Core usually is done by overriding `SaveChanges`.